# How do you Add or Update a JProperty Value in a JObject

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am currently using the following extension method to perform this task, but it almost seems like there should be some existing included method or extension to perform this (or at least a subset of this). If there isn't anything within **Json.NET** then what is the recommended process, or how would I change the code below to be closer to the recommended process.

```
public static partial class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static JObject SetPropertyContent(this JObject source, string name, object content)
    {
        var prop = source.Property(name);

        if (prop == null)
        {
            prop = new JProperty(name, content);

            source.Add(prop);
        }
        else
        {
            prop.Value = JContainer.FromObject(content);
        }

        return source;
    }
}
```

I can confirm the above code works for basic usage, but I'm not certain how well it holds up to broader usage.

The reason I have this extension returning a `JObject` is so that you would be able to chain calls (either multiple calls to this extension or to other methods and extensions).

i.e.,

```
var data = JObject.Parse("{ 'str1': 'test1' }");

data
    .SetPropertyContent("str1", "test2")
    .SetPropertyContent("str3", "test3");

// {
//   "str1": "test2",
//   "str3": "test3"
// }
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: how do you know that what you are doing is `wrong..? or not correct` sounds like codereview is what you want

Comment: code review is what this sounds like

Comment: tbh, i haven't head of codereview yet, is there a simple way of moving this over there?

Comment: You can just do `source[name] = JToken.FromObject(content)` and it will add it or set it as needed.

Comment: wow. i can't believe I didn't try that.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

as @dbc described in the comment, you can simply use the indexer to make this happen.

```
var item = JObject.Parse("{ 'str1': 'test1' }");

item["str1"] = "test2";
item["str3"] = "test3";
```

see the [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DzFsn9) for more details

Comment: Great. But, if I want to Add or Update by LINQ, what should I do?

Comment: I assume you would just `foreach` your enumerable and use the above solution to add or update each element in your enumerable.

Answer (score 5):

Anyone trying to access nested JSON use the approach as in answer by [@pjs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30656251/5697992) adding extra braces as required.

```
JObject item = JObject.Parse("{
   "test": {
       "first": "one",
       "second": "two",
       "nth":   "n"
   }
}");
```

To edit:

```
item["test"]["nth"] = "updated";
```

Updates the JObject to:

```
{
   "test": {
       "first": "one",
       "second": "two",
       "nth":   "updated"
   }
}
```