# How do you Add or Update a JProperty Value in a JObject by using LINQ?

Tags: c#, json, xml, linq, json.net

I want to make JSON file by using JSON.NET.
https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

I have a default json file, and I want to modify some new property values.
Because 'some new property values' is from XML file,
I want to call JObject::Add() with LINQ parameter like,

```
jsonObject.Add(from c in node.Elements() select new JProperty(c.Name.ToString(), c.Value));
```

I found some questions about Add or Update.
[How do you Add or Update a JProperty Value in a JObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30085926/how-do-you-add-or-update-a-jproperty-value-in-a-jobject)
It say 'using indexer' can solve the problems.
But I dont' know how to use indexer with LINQ.

1. jsonObject already has default values.
2. I want to Add or Update with LINQ from xml node.
   Thanks.

Comment: Is this a json serialization or an xml serialization.  Posting should not be marked with both.

Comment: Please include some sample inputs and sample outputs.

Comment: Why does it have to be done *with LINQ*?  Why not just do `foreach (var c in node.Elements()) { jsonObject[c.Name.ToString()] = c.Value; }`

Comment: @dbc You are right.

Answer (score 0):

I found function for merging JSON.
https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/MergeJson.htm
https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_MergeArrayHandling.htm
So, I can make default JObject and merge with new JObject.
Thanks.