# Adding property to a json object in C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm trying to add a property to a json object, which are not root of the json.

example is below.

```
{
    'isFile' : 'true',
    'Values' : {
        'valueName1': 'value1',
        'valueName2': 'value2',
        'valueName3': 'value3',
    }
}
```

after the operation, i want the json file to look like below.

```
{
    'isFile' : 'true',
    'Values' : {
        'valueName1': 'value1',
        'valueName2': 'value2',
        'valueName3': 'value3',
        'valueName4': 'value4'
    }
}
```

I have gotten to the point where I can access Values property through below code.
Where do I go next?

```
JObject appSettings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(jsonString);
string values = appSettings["Values"].ToString();
```

any help?

*Edit
I'm trying to edit values section for local.settings.json file for azure app function in Visual Studio.

Comment: Are you trying to access AppSettings like this?  You know there are already built in ways of doing this...

Comment: `JObject appSettings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(jsonString);
appSettings["Values"]["valueName4"] = "value4";`

Comment: learn how to code json props that are arrays.  you are hard coding a list.

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to access app settings for azure function. how do I do it?

Comment: *how do I do it?* - @CodeNotFound  already gave you the answer: use the indexer.  See [How do you Add or Update a JProperty Value in a JObject](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30085926/3744182).

Comment: No I was asking @maccettura, since he said there is a build in ways of doing this for azure function :(

Comment: @user2662520 if you are accessing an app.config, use the [ConfigurationManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager(v=vs.110).aspx) stuff

Comment: @user2662520 - in that case you should [edit] your question to explain your full requirements, to avoid getting irrelevant answers.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you can do it with a dynamic object

```
        dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(jsonString);
        obj.Values.valueName4 = "value4";
        System.Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj));
```