# Add property dynamically to a json string?

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

I need to add some properties to a json string dynamically. Here is the code I'm using:

```
// set as empty json object
RequestMessage = "{}";
dynamic d = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(RequestMessage);
d.Request = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);
d.RequestOptions = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestOptions);
RequestMessage = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(d);
```

This can add Request and RequestOptions to d, then serialize d back to json string.

It works fine if I know the properties' names, in this case, they are Request and RequestOptions.

Question is: is there a way to do this IF the property name is a variable? for example, something like:

```
private string GetJson(string name, object obj)
{
    // name is "Request"
    // object is request
    ......
    return RequestMessage;
}
```

Is it possible? *I'm using .net + newton json.

thanks

Comment: Why use `dynamic` at all?  Just use a `Dictionary<string, object>`

Comment: Don't use `dynamic`.  The concrete type Json.NET uses for a JSON object is `JObject`, so use that.  See: [How do you add a JToken to an JObject?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15413825/3744182), [How do you Add or Update a JProperty Value in a JObject](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30085926/3744182).  A dictionary as mentioned above would also work.

Comment: the purpose is to add a property to the object dynamically (the object is converted from a json string), then convert it back to json string

Comment: You can add items to a `Dictionary<string, object>` or `JObject` in runtime.

Comment: thanks, dbc. if you added it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you add a JToken to an JObject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15413825/how-do-you-add-a-jtoken-to-an-jobject)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can add properties dynamically to a dynamic object:

```cs
var RequestMessage = "{}";
dynamic d = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(RequestMessage);
d.Request = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { A = 42 });
d.RequestOptions = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { B = 22 });

var name = "SomeMore";
d[name]=11;

RequestMessage = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(d);
```

↓

```
{"Request":"{\"A\":42}","RequestOptions":"{\"B\":22}","SomeMore":11}
```

Comment: Why use `dynamic` instead of `Dictionary<string, object>` or `JObject`?

Comment: in this case `d` actually is a `JObject`